# If A is a non-proper subset of B, can we deduct A=B?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I have the following definition:

> Let $A,B$ be sets. We say that $A$ is a subset of $B$, denoted $A ⊆ B$, **iff** every element of A is also an element of B, i.e.
>   For any object $x$, x$ ∈ A ⇒ x ∈ B$.
>   We say that $A$ is a proper subset of $B$, denoted $A \subsetneq B$, if$ A ⊆ B$ and
>   $A\neq B$.

Note: I know that "$⊆$" is usually used to denote a proper subset and "$\subset$ " is used to denote a subset instead but I guess that is beyond the point of the question, I just copied the textbook content.

My question:

Logically speaking (according to the definitions) $A$ being a subset of $B$ shouldn't imply $A=B$ since that would mean for any object $x$, x$ ∈ A ⇒ x ∈ B$ but this isn't enough to consider $A=B$ as we would need as well for any object $y$, y$ ∈ B ⇒ x ∈ A$ however if $A$ is a subset of $B$ and $A \neq B$ then we would just denote is as a prober subset instead of a subset only, so I find this kind of contradicting.

Comment: $\subsetneq$ [\subsetneq] might be the symbol you're looking for. http://detexify.kirelabs.org is good for these sorts of things

Comment: @JordanMitchellBarrett thank you, edited my post. I just couldn't find it when I looked up on google.

Comment: The definition of *subset* does not rule out the case $A=B$. The definition of *proper* subset rules it our. Thus, no contradiction at all.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so to conclude, we just use it when we don't know if $A=B$ or $A\neq B$ ?

Comment: We use it every time the definition applies. For $A= \{ 1,2 \}$ and $B = \{ 1,2,3 \}$ is it true that $\forall x (x \in A \to x \in B)$ ? Yes; thus, $A \subseteq B$. What about $\forall x (x \in A \to x \in A)$ ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA then in that case are talking about the set $A$ where we can say two things: $A⊆A$ and $A=A$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $A$ is an proper subset of $B$ if $A \neq B$, so if $A$ is an improper subset of $B$, then $A=B$.

Note that $A = B$ if and only if $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$.